# A question about the supremum of a rational set

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

If we have a set $A$ that is defined as a non empty set in rational numbers. Then we use it's $\sup(A)$ to define real numbers as it is not always in the rationals.

My question is, does this mean that if we take $\sup(A)-\epsilon$,

$\epsilon$ being infinitely small, does that mean that that number is a rational and we can express it in $\frac{m}{n}$. Why wouldn't this be true if we have a proof for incompleteness of rationals that states that we can always find a $\beta^²$ that is between let's say the number $2$ and $\alpha^2$. So we can find a rational between any rational and irrational number as far as I understand. How "big" must be $\epsilon$ for us to move from the supremum to a rational number.

If my assumption in the second paragraph is already partially correct, does there exist an irrational number that is infinitely close to another irrational.

I am an undergraduate so that is why my question might be a little too basic.

Comment: What do you mean by $\epsilon$ being infinitely small?

Comment: @ClementYung , by that I mean that we can choose a number that we name $\epsilon$ that is so small that we can come from irrational to rationals. Sort of the same as we have $\epsilon$ when we check the least upper/lower bound that we know that there arent't/are any elements beyond that.

Comment: There may not be such an $\epsilon$. In your context, take $A := \{x \in \Bbb{Q} : x^2 < 2\}$, so clearly $\sup{A} = \sqrt{2}$. Then, for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can always find a rational number between $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2} - \epsilon$.

Comment: @ClementYung So it is not possible that if let's say that we make $\epsilon$ that has infinitely many decimals, so does an irrational number and we subtract that epsilon, we get to a rational. Or let's say that $\epsilon$ has infinitely plus one more decimal, couldn't we somehow hit the "sweet spot" and get to a rational ?

Comment: It seems like you're confused with how infinity works. Infinity is not a number, so there's not such that as "infinity plus one". I'm afraid I don't really understand what you're trying to convey here. What is "make $\epsilon$ that has infinitely many decimals"?

Comment: @ClementYung What I wanted to say is that if a number exists that would reduce an irrational number to a rational?

Comment: And what would you mean by "reduce an irrational number to a rational"?

Comment: @ClementYung By that I mean that we would subtract such a number that would move the irrational point to a rational point on a number line.

Comment: In that case, indeed it's true that given an irrational number $x$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists a number $y \in (0,\epsilon)$ such that $x - y$ is rational (we can truncate the decimal expansion of $y$. However, once again, it wouldn't make sense to let $y$ be "infinitely small", as there's no such that as an infinitely small positive real number.